# Force Https for custom pages

Tags: php, url, yii, https

I followed the following tutorial: [Yii 1.1: URL management for Websites with secure and nonsecure pages](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/)

This is code from `/protected/config/main.php`

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'class' => 'UrlManager',
    'hostInfo' => 'http://goliv.me',
    'secureHostInfo' => 'https://goliv.me',
    'secureRoutes' => array(
        'site/booking',   // site/login action
    ),
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'caseSensitive' => false, 
    'urlSuffix' => '.html',
    'rules' => array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'
    ),
),
```

and this my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I'm facing the following problem only with `site/booking`:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

When I remove this part:

```
'secureRoutes' => array(
    'site/booking'
),
```

Everything works without problems.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The Method does not correcty return true if there is a slash at the end of the route, thus calling site/booking/ will not return true.

```
class UrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
................
/**
     * @param string the URL route to be checked
     * @return boolean if the give route should be serviced in SSL mode
     */
    protected function isSecureRoute($route)
    {
        if ($this->_secureMap === null) {
            foreach ($this->secureRoutes as $r) {
                $this->_secureMap[strtolower($r)] = true;
            }
        }
        $route = strtolower($route);
        if (isset($this->_secureMap[$route])) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return ($pos = strpos($route, '/')) !== false 
                && isset($this->_secureMap[substr($route, 0, $pos)]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but can you be more specific?